# Is there a way to animate parts of a net?

Tags: animation, mesh

[image]I am working on a project where I have to animate a cylindrical net. The top of the net is fixed and the bottom of the net is lifted up by a crane. I have made the net by subdeviding a cylinder and adding the "Wireframe Modifier" and a "Cloth modifier". I have also made the top fixed by selecting the top vertecies and making them a vertex group.
Is there a way I can animate the blue bottom ring to be lifted up until leveled with the red ring?

Comment: please add some screenshots or your blend file so we can better unterstand what you mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I know how to do this is with shape keys.

In object mode, select the object, go to its Data Properties and click on the '+' icon below shape keys to create a new "Basis" shape key.

Click again to create a new key.

Rename this to something meaningful.  I called mine "folded up"[image: shape keys created]

Make sure the new key is selected.

In edit mode move the vertices into the new final position.

Now, in object mode, the "Value" field can be used for key frames.

Select a frame in the playback window.

Set "Value" to something between 0 and 1.

Hover over it and right click.

Select "Insert Keyframe"/ [image: adding a keyframe]

Assign both the top and the bottom to a vertex group:

[image: top and bottom selected]

[image: vertex group PIN]

And add that vertex group as a *Pin Group* in cloth settings:

[image: Pin Group]

For the result below, the net was additionally subdivided (*"simple"* mode, 2 levels) **before** the cloth modifier.

[image: result]